# Filter, cut and paste from one worksheet to another one

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with lots of data. I want to use the Autofilter for column `A` in `Testsheet1`, afterwards cut the **entire row** and paste it to a defined range in `Testsheet2`.

```
Sub CutCopyPaste()

    Dim lrow as Long

    lRow = Worksheets("Testsheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Worksheets("Testsheet1").Range("A1:A" & lRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Test"

    Worksheets("Testsheet1").Range("A1:A" & lRow).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Cut Worksheets("Testsheet2").Range("A1")

End Sub
```

It works totally fine for `copy` but I get an error using `cut`. **Runtime error '438'. Object doesn't support this feature or method.**

Comment: I don't think you can use cut like that.  You might need a Copy/Delete operation.  IIRC Cut does not work on non-contiguous ranges.

Comment: I think it has to do with the filtered data and visible cells, it totally works like copy, you can move it in one go... but not sure if you can while filtered. Try it without filtering.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the Job For you:

```
Sub CutCopyPaste()

    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim ws

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6")
        lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1:A" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Test"
    End With


    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A1:A" & lrow).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    ws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A1:A" & lrow).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete


End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, I tested it and works:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CutCopyPaste()

    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim ws

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TestSheet2")

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Testsheet1")
        lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1:A" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Test"
        .Range("A1:A" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Cut ws.Range("A1")
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. Cut doesn't work on Multiple Range Selection.

Comment: I did @Damian ... It throws an Error.